# Unable to decrypt encrypted message using another instance of cipher

Tags: ruby, aes-gcm

I am using ruby version 2.4.0 and openssl version "OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014", I am trying to implement an encryption/decryption for a security layer.

The code works fine if I write it as follows using the same cipher object.

```
# Example 1

require 'openssl'
require 'base64'

data = "Hello1"

cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES128.new :GCM
cipher.encrypt
iv  = cipher.random_iv # random iv
key = cipher.random_key # 128 byte key
cipher.key = key
cipher.iv = iv
enc_data  = cipher.update(data) + cipher.final

cipher.decrypt
cipher.key = key
cipher.iv = iv
original_data = cipher.update(enc_data) + cipher.final

if data == original_data
  puts "Yes"
end
```

But in the second example where I have instantiated a second cipher object for decrypting I am getting a CipherError.

```
# Example 1

require 'openssl'
require 'base64'

def encrypt(data)
  cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES128.new :GCM
  cipher.encrypt
  key = cipher.random_key
  iv  = cipher.random_iv
  cipher.key = key
  cipher.iv = iv
  enc_data = cipher.update(data) + cipher.final
  return enc_data, key, iv
end

def decrypt(data, key, iv)
  cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES128.new :GCM
  cipher.decrypt
  cipher.key = key
  cipher.iv  = iv
  cipher.update(data) + cipher.final
end

data = 'Hello2'
enc_data, key, iv = encrypt(data)
original_data = decrypt(enc_data, key, iv)

if data == original_data
  puts "Yes"
end


OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError:
from (irb):93:in `final'
from (irb):93:in `decrypt'
from (irb):98
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCM mode requires a bit more setup, compared to, say, CBC mode.

Documentation: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Cipher.html#class-OpenSSL::Cipher-label-Authenticated+Encryption+and+Associated+Data+-28AEAD-29

> An example using the GCM (Galois/Counter Mode). You have 16 bytes `key`, 12 bytes (96 bits) `nonce` and the associated data **`auth_data`**. ... Now you are the receiver. You know the `key` and have received `nonce`, `auth_data`, `encrypted` and **`tag`** through an untrusted network.

Here's the updated code:

```
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'

def encrypt(data)
  cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES128.new(:GCM).encrypt
  key = cipher.random_key
  iv  = cipher.random_iv
  cipher.key = key
  cipher.iv = iv
  cipher.auth_data = ''
  enc_data = cipher.update(data) + cipher.final
  return enc_data, key, iv, cipher.auth_tag
end

def decrypt(data, key, iv, auth_tag)
  cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES128.new(:GCM).decrypt
  cipher.decrypt
  cipher.key = key
  cipher.iv  = iv
  cipher.auth_data = ''
  cipher.auth_tag = auth_tag
  cipher.update(data) + cipher.final
end

data = 'Hello2'
enc_data, key, iv, auth_tag = encrypt(data)
original_data = decrypt(enc_data, key, iv, auth_tag)

if data == original_data
  puts "Yes"
end
```

Comment: If  you use an empty string for `auth_data` you can leave the corresponding lines away.

Comment: @andiba: indeed. Let's keep them for completeness, though.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev i tried without the auth_data and auth_tag setting. and it worked (both encryption and decryption) if cipher object is the same for encryption and decryption. but it didn't work for two different objects. Can you help me understand why it is like that ?.

Comment: @RubyMiner: because when you reuse cipher object, its (random) `auth_tag` doesn't change.

Comment: @RubyMiner: Read the text behind the link provided  SergioTulentsev: It's a security feature called AEAD (Authenticated Encryption in combination with Associated Data)...

Comment: This works perfectly if there is a auth_tag, is the behavior is same in other languages such as java ? Anyone knows ?

Comment: I'd expect that yes, it's the same everywhere. Else how do you expect to communicate between apps written in different languages?

Comment: AFAIK, it should be, its not language dependent. its the way the authenticated encryption algorithm is designed.

Comment: As per this java is appending the auth_tag and iv is prefixed, this could be the reason I am not able to decrypt the payload. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/124137/how-authentication-tag-is-calculated-in-aes-gcm-256.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev cracked this, java does appends the auth_tag after the encrypted message in GCM mode. In ruby we need to extract the last 16 bytes and use it as auth_tag. This worked for me, in my case the iv was prefixed before the encrypted data as well.